# Why Hibernate fires an update when "mappedby" is absent in a OneToMany relationship?

Tags: java, hibernate

Hibernate seems to fire an additional "Update" statement when mappedby attribute is missing in a OneToMany association . I verified the example given in this link : http://levelup.lishman.com/hibernate/associations/one-to-many.php Can someone please explain why the Update is fired when the relationship is not bidirectional ?

Comment: Can you elaborate? What is your expected update and what is the additional one? For a **uni**directional relationship you must not have `mappedby` (because the relationship does not exist on the other side).

Comment: With a One to Many association between Continent and Country tables when we use only JoinColumn (with OneToMany and ManyToOne on each side) and try to add a country to a particular continent, first an insert is fired and then an update on the same country for its continent